# C# abstract record with abstract Equals method

Tags: c#, record

Why are we not allowed to do the following for a record

```
abstract record AA
{
  public abstract bool Equals(AA other);
}

record BB:AA
{
  public override bool Equals(AA other)// error as it is already implemented
  {
    //do some thing
  }
}
```

while it is totally acceptable for classes?

```
abstract class AA
{
   public abstract bool Equals(AA other);
}

class BB:AA
{
  public override bool Equals(AA other)
  {
    //do some thing
  }
}
```

By the way, I am doing this implementation to enforce the Equals check to cascade to its derived classes.

**Edit:** just to give context on why am I interested on this is because I am currently creating an [library/autogenerator](https://github.com/marlond18/EMDD.KtEquatable) for IEquatable.

**Edit/Info 2:** Based on the comments, I have done some tests. since the abstract Equals method of record can't be overridden, I tried leaving it as is.

```
public abstract record AA
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string? Prop2 { get; set; }
    public string? Prop5 { get; set; }
    public abstract bool Equals(AA? other);
}

public record BB : AA
{
    public string? Prop3 { get; set; }
}
```

The result I get an error of ***System.BadImageFormatException: Bad IL format.***

All in all, abstract Equals method on records is not just an unnecessary implementation but is also a bad one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because compiler already implements equality methods for records. Check [Value equality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record#value-equality) of records:

> To implement value equality, the compiler synthesizes the following methods:
>
> - An override of Object.Equals(Object).
> - This method is used as the basis for the Object.Equals(Object, Object) static method when both parameters are non-null.
> - A virtual Equals method whose parameter is the record type. This method implements IEquatable.
> - An override of Object.GetHashCode().
> - Overrides of operators == and !=.

It means that there's not need to enforce the implementation of `Equals` method in the base abstract record.

If you still want to have custom `Equals` method implementation and derive from some base record you could do so by declaring virtual `Equals` method with the derived type as an argument:

```
abstract record AA
{
    // Redundant in case of records and can be omitted.
    public abstract bool Equals(AA other);
}

record BB : AA
{
    public virtual bool Equals(BB other)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: The page you linked to also says *"If a record type has a method that matches the signature of any synthesized method, the compiler doesn't synthesize that method"*, which means that, in this particular case, the compiler should **not** synthesize such a method.

Comment: In case of inheritance the `public bool Equals(AA other)` is generated in base record, which causes an error. It would be valid to create `public virtual bool Equals(BB other)` in the derived record though.

Comment: All in all, not only is ```public abstract bool Equals(AA other);``` an unnecessary implementation for records, but also a bad one.

Comment: @MKtsisD I couldn't prove in my tests that adding abstract `Equals` to abstract record changes behavior in any scenario that I tests. It can be misleading, yes, but not really harmful. I would also advice against a base record for records as when comparing records if two different derived types lead to comparison of one record and a `null` due to the underlying casting.